# Java / Ebean And Or Query

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm trying to perform an sql query as so:

```
select * from conversations where (user_1 = user_1_id  and user_2 = user_2_id )  or (user_1 = user_2_id  and user_2 = user_1_id )
```

I'm writing it in Ebean as so:

```
Conversation conversation = Ebean.find(Conversation.class)
                                .where()
                                    .and(Expr.eq("user_1", user_1_id), Expr.eq("user_2", user_2_id))
                                    .or(Expr.eq("user_1", user_2_id), Expr.eq("user_2", user_1_id))
                                .findUnique();
```

However this gives the following query:

```
select * from conversation where (user_1 = user_1_id  and user_2 = user_2_id )  and (user_1 = user_2_id  or user_2 = user_1_id )
```

I've been looking at the documentation, but I'm not getting a clear idea about how to refine the query to match my needs.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [JavaDoc](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Expr.html) (it has an *or* expression as an example):

```
// Example: Using an Expr.or() method
Query<Order> query = Ebean.createQuery(Order.class);
query.where( 
            Expr.or(Expr.eq("status", Order.NEW),
                Expr.gt("orderDate", lastWeek));

List<Order> list = query.findList();
```

This perhaps makes it a bit easier to understand why this code:

```
.or(Expr.eq("user_1", user_2_id), Expr.eq("user_2", user_1_id))
```

Results in:

> (user_1 = user_2_id  or user_2 = user_1_id )

You are, so to speak, using the *or* expression *inside* your second condition, instead of *between* the two conditions.

You need to put the `or` method first:

```
Conversation conversation = Ebean.find(Conversation.class)
    .where().or(
        Expr.and(Expr.eq("user_1", user_1_id), Expr.eq("user_2", user_2_id)),
        Expr.and(Expr.eq("user_1", user_2_id), Expr.eq("user_2", user_1_id)))
    .findUnique();
```

This should put the *or* between your paranthesises, and an *and* condition inside them.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had tried something similar, but it wouldn't compile so I assumed I was on the wrong track.

This worked though, so thanks!